# Can't get files uploaded by php on Apache virtualhost

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4, wordpress, ubuntu-14.04

A couple of weeks ago i got the idea that i should host a Wordpress blogg on my VPS under a different domain name. I set up my virtual host following a guide i found on digital ocean tutorials [How To Set Up Multiple WordPress Sites on a Single Ubuntu VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-wordpress-sites-on-a-single-ubuntu-vps).

I can get the virtual host to show the wordpress site and i can do most tasks on the installation. But when i try to upload images from the admin section i get an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

I have tried a lot of the remedies i found through Google but none of them seem to work. I have tried with both a single php.ini file for both hosts and one for each host. 
Tried to fix it using a .htaccess file in the document root.

All of these things have gotten me nowhere closer to being able to upload files. I even tried installing Joomla to rule out Wordpress being the issue.

A little more info about my setup:
Serverhost: Ipeer
Platform: Ubuntu 14.04 with LAMP
Database: MySQL
Site 1: Opencart
Site 2: Wordpress ( the one i try to get working)

Is there anyone who encountered anything like this?

All sugestions to get the situation remedied are welcome. If you need more informaion i'll gladly provide this asap.

Best Regards
Robert

Comment: Are there any errors showing up in your php error log? Are all file permissions correct?

Comment: I have tried with file permission 777 without any result. The php error file is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

- deactivate all plugins and see if the problem persists. If it solves
  the problem, activate plugins one by one until you find the
  problematic one

  - revert to Twenty Twelve theme and see if the issue is theme-specific
  - delete any inactive plugins
  - reinstall WordPress manually from a freshly downloaded copy except wp-content. Do not overwrite files/ folders but delete them before
    reinstalling.
  - run the upgrade manually via wp-admin/upgrade.php

Backup your site including database so that you can restore in case anything goes wrong